# Property X does not exist on exist on type App

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
import React from "react";
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
import "./App.css";
import SideBar from "./components/sidebar/SideBar";
import Content from "./components/content/Content";

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      isOpen: false,
      isMobile: true
    };

    this.previousWidth = -1;
  }

  updateWidth() {
    const width = window.innerWidth;
    const widthLimit = 576;
    const isMobile = width <= widthLimit;
    const wasMobile = this.previousWidth <= widthLimit;

    if (isMobile !== wasMobile) {
      this.setState({
        isOpen: !isMobile
      });
    }

    this.previousWidth = width;
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.updateWidth();
    window.addEventListener("resize", this.updateWidth.bind(this));
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    window.removeEventListener("resize", this.updateWidth.bind(this));
  }

  toggle = () => {
    this.setState({ isOpen: !this.state.isOpen });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App wrapper">
        <SideBar toggle={this.toggle} isOpen={this.state.isOpen} />
        <Content toggle={this.toggle} isOpen={this.state.isOpen} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

In the App.tsx file i am  getting error error "Property previousWidth does not exist on type App.tsx" for the previousWidth property. How can I resolve the error? Do I need to define any interface? Property is used for the adjusting the width of the window according to the type of the window.

Comment: what line causes the error, and when does it happens

Comment: I am getting the error in all three lines where previousWidth is written. I am getting the compilation error.